# How to use google recaptcha in my custom form

Tags: magento2.4.1, google-recaptcha

I am following this link https://magebug.blogspot.com/2018/05/magento-2-add-google-recaptcha-in.html

The link suggests add a controller, i have already a controller file, how to add more than one controller under  **execute()**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add script in file you want to use google Recaptcha

```
<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js" type="text/javascript" xml="space"></script>
```

Add captcha code to phtml or block/page where you want to add Recaptcha in the form

```
<div class="form-group required">   //change class as per themes
        <div class="g-recaptcha required" id="recaptcha"
             data-sitekey="your-site-key">
        </div>
             <div style="display:none" id="error-msg">
                  <span><?php echo __('This is a required field.') ?></span>
             </div>
</div>
```

If the captcha validation not working then add the below code:

```
<script>
    function checkCaptcha() {
        if ((jQuery('#g-recaptcha-response').val()) === '') {
            jQuery('#error-msg').css('display', 'block');
            jQuery('#error-msg').css('color', '#df280a');
            jQuery('#error-msg').css('font-size', 13);
            return false;
        }
        else {
            jQuery('#error-msg').css('display', 'none');
        }
    }
</script>
```

In form starting add onSubmit="return checkCaptcha() ;" event like:

```
<form class="form contact" action="<?php echo $block->getFormAction(); ?>" id="contact-form" method="post" onSubmit="return checkCaptcha() ;">
</form>
```

Comment: Still not working, can u pls help me, Code: https://codeshare.io/2BNrqn

Comment: Check how to create "data-sitekey" for reCaptcha and generate then use that generated data-sitekey here

Comment: Yes i am using my sitekay.

Comment: You donot use any site key, first of all generate site key then add it in data-siteKey check this link https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/display

Comment: I am added my site : <div class="g-recaptcha required" id="recaptcha"
                            data-sitekey="ipthjihyiohytihnijhthnthtrhrthtr0t">

Comment: And if you are using it on localhost then use 127.0.0.1/... rather than localhost/... 
Either it will not work

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/120983/discussion-between-zus-and-arun-kumar).

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using the following techniques:
a) Create an observer for your customer form's controller,
b) Utilize Magento\ReCapchaUi\Model\RequestHandlerInterface::execute() and use your custom request as key to handle the request.